# Why is permission denied on this folder?

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem

I'm trying to understand why I do not have access to a sub-folder in my "Downloads" folder. The folder in question has the following rights:

```
drw-r--r--   29 laurent  staff   986B Feb 20 14:06 Example
```

and `whoami` gives 'laurent'. So as I understand, anybody can view this folder and I am the owner.

However, when I do `cd Example`, I'm getting:

```
bash: cd: Example/: Permission denied
```

In fact it seems to be true of all the sub-folders in my "Downloads" folder, none of them can be accessed (without using sudo). Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Don't you need x permission to see inside a folder?  Like drwxr-xr-x or so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be able to list or enter a directory you need execute permission

e.g

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 mark  staff      68 18 Mar 14:00 example
```

Use [chmod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) to change the permissions, also check the [setting of umask](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2202) to see the default

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you. I've fixed it by running `chmod -R 755 *` on the folder. It seems it's actually BitTorrent which is creating all these folders with the wrong permissions. Is it possible to force a umask for a particular application?

Comment: If a program is producing different file permissions to all other programs then it is explicitly setting permissions